# Sentry2 on Laravel find if email exists

Tags: php, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

Is there a way to find an user by email with sentry 2 on laravel? `Sentry::findUserById(1)` does find by id I wanted to find by the user email, is there way way?

I've also tried `$users = User::all();` but it throws me the following error:

[image]

Can anyone explain how I may get user's all info by user's email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Find the user using the user email address
$user = Sentry::findUserByLogin('john.doe@example.com');
```